# what can be said about the degree of this polynomial?

Tags: complex-analysis

Please just give Hint of the following problem:

$f$ is a polynomial in $\mathbb{C}$, $\alpha,\beta$ be complex number with $\beta\neq 0$, given that $f(z)=\alpha$ when $z^5=\beta$, what can we say about the degree of $f$?

what I have?If I take it is of degree $n$, $f$ is onto, entire,open map, $f(z)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_nz^n$

Comment: It is not clear whether "when" is supposed to mean "only when".

Comment: I agree with Eckhard, although the only difference it makes to the final answer as to possible degree is whether or not the constant polynomial case is allowed.

Comment: Is the answer unique? If I take $\alpha=\beta=1$ then any $f(z)=z^{5n}$ works.

Comment: @Pentelis: It depends on what you mean by unique; there is not a unique possible degree, but there is a unique set of possible degrees.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints:

- How many $z$ are there such that $z^5=\beta$?
- How many times can a degree $n$ polynomial take the same value?

Comment: okay can I use this result: $f$ is analytic at $z_0$, $f(z_0)=w_0$ and that $f(z)-w_0$ has a zero of order $n$ at $z_0$. If $\epsilon>0$ is small enough, there exist $\delta>0$ such that $\forall a,|a-w_0|<\delta$ the equation $f(z)=w_0$ has exactly $n$ roots in the disc $|z-z_0|<\epsilon$,  here $f(z)=\alpha$ has $5$ roots namely all $5$ th roots of $\beta$, so degree $5$?

Comment: @Panu: That theorem is not needed, and I don't see how it is relevant.  We don't know from what's given what the orders of the zeros are.  One way to proceed is to note that if $f(z_0)=\alpha$, then $f(z)-\alpha=g(z)(z-z_0)$ for some polynomial $g$.  We can apply this result to $g$ if there are more zeros.  You will not be able to determine the exact degree, but you can give a bound (and be careful about one special case).  You are correct that there are $5$ given solutions to $f(z)=\alpha$.

Comment: got your point,and then I can say degree $\le 5$, but what disaster will happen if degree $>5$?

Comment: @Panu: That is incorrect.  For example, can a degree one polynomial, $f(z)=a_0+a_1z$ with $a_1\neq 0$, take the same value more than once?  A degree two polymonial can: For example, if $f(z)-\alpha = (z-z_1)(z-z_2)$, then $f$ is a degree two polynomial that take the value $\alpha$ twice.

Comment: @Panu: Because the answer is accepted, I am curious: Have you completed the problem?

Comment: No, not rigoriusly, but just got the idea what you told.

Comment: @Panu: OK, I'm not asking for rigor, but have you gotten the answer?

Comment: yes it will be bounded by $5$

Comment: @Panu: That is vague; bounded below, or bounded above?  Is degree 4 possible? 5? 6? etc. The problem is probably looking for a complete clear description of the possibilities.

Comment: @Panu: As indicated in a previous comment, that is incorrect.  As you agreed, a degree 1 polynomial cannot take the same value twice, so in particular degree 1 polynomials are not possible solutions to this problem.  How many times can a degree 2 polynomial take the same value?

Comment: oho! then I am really not getting correctly. say $f(z)=2z+z^2$ takes $0$ once and $f(z)=z^2$ takes $0$ twice.

Comment: @Panu: Let me ask a specific modified form of the second question in my answer:  If a polynomial has degree $n\geq 1$, what is the maximum number of zeros the polynomial can have?  If you can answer this then you're on a good track.

Comment: @Panu: Regarding the examples in your last comment, that is backwards:  $2z+z^2$ has 2 zeros, at $z=0$ and $z=-2$, whereas $z^2$ has one zero (with multiplicity two) at $z=0$.  But in both cases, there can be at most 2 zeros, (or exactly two counting multiplicity).  Can a degree 2 polynomial *ever* have three zeros?

Comment: no, if it have more than 2 zeros then it must be zero polynomial. and it can have max $n$ zeros if deg is n

Comment: @Panu: Right.  So now we can turn that around: If a polynomial does have $n$ or more zeros, then what is the possible degree?

Comment: aha :P :P, blush.., $\ge n$..thanku thanku..so it will be $\ge 5$ in our case,

Comment: @Panu: Right; the possible exception is the constant polynomial, $f(z)\equiv \alpha$.  A degree $5$ example will occur with $f(z)=\alpha + (z^5 - \beta)$, but any higher degree is also possible.